# Generalized Impulse responses VAR(2)

Tags: impulse-response

I have a VAR(2) model:

$\textbf{y}_t=\textbf{A}_1\textbf{y}_{t-1}+\textbf{A}_2\textbf{y}_{t-2}+\textbf{u}_t$

where $\textbf{y}_t$ is a 2x1 vector, $\textbf{A}_1, \textbf{A}_2$ are two 2x2 matrices and $\textbf{u}_t$ is a 2x1 vector of white noise distrubuted as $N(0,\Sigma)$. Notice that $\Sigma$ is not diagonal, i.e. the noise are contemporaneous correlated. Moreover: the two matrices $\textbf{A}_1, \textbf{A}_2$ are respectively:

\begin{array}{cc}
   0.6 & 0.2 \\
   0.2 & 0.4 \\
  \end{array}

and

\begin{array}{cc}
   -0.2 & 0.2 \\
   0.4 & -0.4 \\
  \end{array}

and $\Sigma$
\begin{array}{cc}
   -0.2 & 0.3 \\
   0.1 & -0.4 \\
  \end{array}

Can someone help me in writing $\textbf{y}_{t+h}$ foh $h=1,2$ as a function of $\textbf{y}_0$ and $\textbf{y}_{-1}$ only? Notice that I have that $\textbf{y}_0=(1,1)$ and $\textbf{y}_{-1}=(0,0)$.

This will be needed to calculat the generalized impulse response function:

$IR_{it}(h)=E_t[\textbf{y}_{t+h}|u_{it=k},\textbf{y}_{t-1}.. ]-E_t[\textbf{y}_{t+h}|\textbf{y}_{t-1}.. ]$

Answer (score 1):

You only need to substitute t+h into your original equation:

> $_=_1_{−1}+_2_{−2}+_$

So you would have:

> $_{+h}=_1_{+h−1}+_2_{+h−2}+_{+h}$

When h=1,2 respectievly

- $_{+1}=_1_{}+_2_{-1}+_{+1}$
- $_{+2}=_1_{+1}+_2_{}+_{+2}$

When t=-1 and h=1,2 respectievly

- $_{0}=_1_{-1}+_2_{-2}+_{0}$
- $_{1}=_1_{0}+_2_{-1}+_{1}$

When t=0 and h=1,2 respectievly

- $_{1}=_1_{0}+_2_{-1}+_{1}$
- $_{2}=_1_{1}+_2_{0}+_{2}$

Now you have your ingredeints for you complete solution.

> $_{1}$ is a function of $_{0}$ and $_{-1}$
>   and
>   $_{2}$ is a function of $_{1}$ and $_{0}$

Comment: Unofortunately this is not what I meant. My aim is to express $\textbf{y}_{t+1}$ and $\textbf{y}_{t+1}$ as functions of $\textbf{y}_{-1}$ and $\textbf{y}_{0}$ only leaving the $t$ index generic, i.e. I am not allowed to arbitrary fix $t$. Essentially, my problem is to derive a \enquote{nice} representation of $\textbf{y}_{t+1}$ by iteratively substituting backwards until time 0 and 1, but I have troubles in seeing the right pattern

Comment: You should look carefully at the answer. What you seek is there.  Even though I didn't spell it out for you.